# Change buton color when get axios response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a react controler that call a endpoint. When I get the response I display the information in an object and I want to change a color of a buton to represent if the response was a 200 or a 404.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./../App.css";
import axios from "axios";
const MicroService = (props) => {
  const [personsGet, setPersonGet] = useState([]);

  function llamadaAxiosGet (url) {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        setPersonGet(res.data);
        return res.status;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        return error.status;
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Microservicio:</h2>
      <BotonLlamada
        url={`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`}
        textBoton={"Llamada al servicio y display all"}
        llamadaAxiosGet={llamadaAxiosGet}
      />
      {personsGet.map((person) => (
        <li key={person.name}>{person.name}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

function BotonLlamada(props) {
  const [colorButon, setColorButon] = useState("");
  const [estado , setEstado]= useState(0);

  const onClickbuton = () => {
    setEstado(props.llamadaAxiosGet(props.url));
    setEstado(props.llamada);
    if (estado === 200) {
      setColorButon("buttonGreen");
    } else if (estado > 399) {
      setColorButon("buttonRed");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (estado > 399) {
      setColorButon("buttonRed");
    } else if (estado === 200) {
      setColorButon("buttonGreen");
    }
  },[estado]);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClickbuton} className={colorButon}>
        {props.textBoton}
      </button>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MicroService;
```

So in the code, because axios is async, this will receive the response after finish the method onClick in the buton but the buton won't change color.
Can someone helps?

Comment: You're changing the class of the button. Is there a CSS rule somewhere that changes the button's color based on the class?

Comment: yes, setColorButon("buttonRed"); this will check in a css and change it

Comment: Can you please make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you shold move the `llamadaAxiosGet` function call in the `BotonLlamada` component and pass the `setPersonGet` state property to it:

```
const MicroService = (props) => {
  const [personsGet, setPersonGet] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Microservicio:</h2>
      <BotonLlamada
        textBoton={"Llamada al servicio y display all"}
        setPersonGet={setPersonGet}
      />
      {personsGet.map((person) => (
        <li key={person.name}>{person.name}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

function BotonLlamada(props) {
  const [colorButon, setColorButon] = useState("");
  const [estado , setEstado]= useState(0);

  function llamadaAxiosGet () {
    axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then((res) => {
        props.setPersonGet(res.data);
        setEstado(res.status);
        setColorButon("buttonGreen");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        setEstado(error.status);
        setColorButon("buttonRed");
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (estado > 399) {
      setColorButon("buttonRed");
    } else if (estado === 200) {
      setColorButon("buttonGreen");
    }
  },[estado]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => llamadaAxiosGet() } className={colorButon}>
        {props.textBoton}
      </button>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MicroService;
```

Comment: That is perfect! I though that I have to do the call to the axios in the parent because the information was going to be receive in the parent but with props.setPersonGet(res.data) you fixed all!
Sir, you are a genious!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're setting your state to a promise of number.

A simple fix would be:

```js
const onClickbuton = () => {
  props.llamadaAxiosGet(props.url)
    .then(status => setEstado(status));
};
```

You could also refactor and shift your logic up to the parent component.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./../App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function BotonLlamada({ colour, onClick, textBoton }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick} className={colour}>
        {textBoton}
      </button>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}

const MicroService = (props) => {
  const [personsGet, setPersonGet] = useState([]);
  const [colour, setColour] = useState("");

  function llamadaAxiosGet(url) {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        setPersonGet(res.data);
        return res.status;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        return error.status;
      })
      .then((status) => {
        if (status > 399) {
          setColour("buttonRed");
        } else if (status === 200) {
          setColour("buttonGreen");
        }
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Microservicio:</h2>
      <BotonLlamada
        textBoton={"Llamada al servicio y display all"}
        onClick={() =>
          llamadaAxiosGet(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
        }
        colour={colour}
      />
      {personsGet.map((person) => (
        <li key={person.name}>{person.name}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MicroService;
```

Comment: I know this comment change a little bit the scope of my original question, if you have 2 botons because they share the state of color, you change them all.
But for one boton works very well :) Thanks so much! You are a genious too!